# Twig batch filter with if condition for creating 3 columns gallery table

Tags: symfony, if-statement, twig, batch-processing

I would like to create a gallery with three columns and I have used twig batch filter. Is it possible to add an if condition so that all disabled images won't be listed? My example is not working:

```
    <table>
    {% for items in content.galleries|batch(3) if items.enabled %}
        <tr>
            {% for cell in items %}
                <td><img src="{{ asset(cell.image) }}"></td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Comment: Try to put your if statement in the for

Comment: If I put "if statement" inside the for there will be some rows with less than three cells.